# Compute average velocity of a particle over a given time interval

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I am really stuck with my math problem, would appreciate the answer below.

> A particle moves on a line away from its initial position so that after $t$ hours it is $s = 4t^2 + t$ miles from its initial position. Find the average velocity of the particle over the interval $[1, 4]$. Include units in your answer.

Comment: Just to clarify, is $[1,4]$ the interval of time $t$ or the interval of position $s$?

Comment: Look up the definition of "average velocity" in your textbook or course notes. One of the answers below uses what _I_ consider to be the definition of average velocity; with any luck it matches yours.

Answer (score 4):

$\text{ average velocity over } [1,4]=\frac{s(4)-s(1)}{4-1}$